# Python: read CSV row by row and create a file per row

Tags: python, csv, text-files

Basically I want to read my CSV and create one text file per row.
My CSV content is : `Grenouille,1139,287,252,164,2017-03-04-21_35_19.jpg,1920,1080`

I've done the following code:

```
import sys
import csv

with open('labels_grenouilles.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))
    for row in spamreader:
        f = open(str(spamreader[5]) + ".txt", "a")
        f.write(str(spamreader[0]) + " " + str(spamreader[1]) + " " + str(spamreader[2]) + " " + str(spamreader[3]) + " " + str(spamreader[4]))
        f.close()
```

but instead of creating each time a new file it creates something like that :
[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: you need to use `row` in the loop not `spamreader`

Comment: Also, no need to create a list, just iterate over reader. And why not use csv.writer? And better open the file using `with`

Comment: so I could fix my issue now I'll optimise it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the `for` loop for each element of `spamreader`. In this case, your `spamreader` is a list, so if you use `spamreader[5]` to create a file you'll get the same value everytime, since you're using the 6th element of the list everytime in `open()`.

Also using `append` in `(open(spamreader[5], "a")` this will create the file if it doesn't exist or will simply add at the end of its content if it exists.

So, in conclusion, you're opening the same file everytime because you're using `spamreader[5]` in the `for` loop, and that's the same value everytime.

My guess is that you want to use `row` in `open()` instead of `spamreader`